# Accessing MasterPage variable in content page

Tags: asp.net, variables, master-pages

I am trying to reference a variable within my MasterPage but I am receiving errors.

I have tried

```
<%@ MasterType" %>
```

which gives the following error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0030:
>   Cannot convert type
>   'IPAMIntranet.IPAMIntranetMaster' to
>   'ASP.ipamintranetmaster_master'

and

```
string tVar = ((MyNamespace.MyMasterPage)Master).variable
```

which gives the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'ASP.ipamintranetmaster_master' to
>   type
>   'IPAMIntranet.IPAMIntranetMaster'.

Does anyone know what is happening or am I missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out by using an interface instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the virtual path to the Masterpage in the content page.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="Master.Master" %>
```

Comment: I did try 
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/IPAMIntranetMaster.Master" %>
and I am getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, it seems that your master page either isn't the type `IPAMIntranet.IPAMIntranetMaster`, or doesn't inherit from `IPAMIntranet.IPAMIntranetMaster`, the only way to resolve this would be to make it inherit, or make sure the type is correct.

The `MasterType` directive can take the whatever class the Master is castable to, it's mainly for intellisense.  You can provide either the `VirtualPath` to the Master or `TypeName`, which can be the Master's class, a base class, or an interface, whichever is more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: This is the first line in the HTML code for the MasterPage:
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="IPAMIntranetMaster.Master.cs" CodeBehind="IPAMIntranetMaster.Master.cs" Inherits="IPAMIntranet.IPAMIntranetMaster" %>

Comment: @mattgcon - What does your `@Page` directive look like for this page?

Comment: This is my content page directive:

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/IPAMIntranetMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="IPAMPeople_HomePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="IPAMIntranet.IPAM_People.IPAMPeople_HomePage" %>